# Question about finding exact values of $\arcsin(-4)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

So this might be a bit of a dumb question.. but how would you go about finding exact values of $\arcsin(-4)$?

I thought that arcsins domain is $-\pi/2 \leq \arcsin(x) \leq \pi/2$ (aka $-1 \leq x \leq 1$)

so wouldn't $x = -4$ be out of this domain?

Comment: Not defined.${}{}{}$

Comment: The range of $\sin$ function is $[-1,1]$, so, it's inverse has no pre-image of $-4.$

Comment: You *can* define $\arcsin(-4)$ (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms)), but you need tools from complex analysis.

Comment: You're confusing the domain of $\arcsin$ ($=$  the range of $\sin$) and its range.

Answer (score 1):

You are right If you find  a solution in $\mathbb{R}$, since $\mbox{arcsin} (-4)=\alpha$ means that $\sin \alpha=-4$, that is impossible because the real function $\sin x$ has range $[-1,1]$ for $x \in  \mathbb{R}$.

But you can find a solution in $\mathbb{C}$. Here, using the [logarithmic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms) of the inverse trigonometric functions you have:
$$
\mbox{arcsin} (-4)=-i\ln(-4i+\sqrt{1-16})=-i\ln[i(\sqrt{15}-4)]
$$
that , using [complex logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Complex_logarithm), becomes:
$$
=-i[\ln(4-\sqrt{15})-\dfrac{i\pi}{2}]=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}-i\ln(4
-\sqrt{15})$$
that, since $(4-\sqrt{15})(4+\sqrt{15})=1$ you can also write as:
$$
-\dfrac{\pi}{2}+i\ln(4
+\sqrt{15})
$$

Comment: Actually that's not quite right: $\sin(\pi/2 + i \ln(4+\sqrt{15}) = +4$, not $-4$.  You seem to have lost a $-$ sign somewhere.

Comment: @RobertIsrael. Thank you. There was some typos.... I've fixed (i hope).